# structure within an array cell coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

I've been trying to create a data structure, but I'm having a hard time.  I am trying to create a data structure like this:

```
{
    "vehicle": [
        {
            "inv_id": "123412",
            "year": "2013",
            "make": "Jeep",
            "model": "Grand Cherokee"
        },
        {
            "inv_id": "1224522",
            "year": "2013",
            "make": "Jeep",
            "model": "Grand Cherokee"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is what I've tried with no luck.

```
<cfset result["vehicle"] = []>
<cfoutput>
<cfloop query="qinv">
    #arrayAppend("result.vehicle,{})#
    <cfloop array="#result.vehicle#" index="i">
        #structInsert(result.vehicle[i], "inventory_id", qInv.inventory_id)#
        #structInsert(result.vehicle[i], "year", qInv.year)#
        #structInsert(result.vehicle[i], "make", qInv.make)#
        #structInsert(result.vehicle[i], "model", qInv.model)#
    </cfloop>
</cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

This is throwing a coldfusion error, `The value coldfusion.runtime.Struct cannot be converted to a number.` on the first structInsert line.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I believe it's the array loop that's causing you grief.  I see no reason to loop through an array immediately after adding an element to it.

Comment: is this - <cfloop array="#result.vehicle# index="i> - a typo in your example, or is that actually what your code says?

Comment: It's a typo, which I have fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need that array loop... think about it: what are you looping over? It's an empty array. All you need to do is append the struct to the array:

```
<cfset arrayAppend( result.vehicle,{
    "inventory_id" = qInv.inventory_id,
    "year" =  qInv.year,
    "make" = qInv.make,
    "model" = qInv.model
})>
```

Comment: is this - `<cfset arrayAppend("result.vehicle,{` - a typo in your example, or is that actually what your code says? ;)

Comment: oh... just noticed it's a typo copied from the question code. Still a bit sloppy for you though. :P